# JQuery mobile 1.3.2 : $.mobile.loading stopped working on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I'm having troubles to get `$.mobile.loading` working properly... It was working fine for a long time, and since I've updated my iOS to the last version (9.x), it's working partially. I mean, sometimes it does work and it shows the loading message, but most of the time it doesn't show anything. I'm running iOS 9.1.3 and tested on both Safari and Firefox iOS.

I've tested on an old iPhone 4S still running on ios 6.x and the loader is working fine !

Also, it's working under Android. Tested it on my computer, and it's working on Chrome and Firefox but not with Safari.

Is there a known bug involving jQuery / jQuery Mobile on the latest version of Safari / iOS ?

**Here is my code :**

```
function showLoadingPage() {
    $('body').append("<div class='ui-loader-background' onClick='$.mobile.loading(\"hide\");'> </div>"); //Fond opaque lors du chargement

    var $this = $( this ),
        //theme = $this.jqmData("theme") || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme,
        theme = "b",
        //msgText = $this.jqmData("msgtext") || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text,
        msgText = "Chargement ...",
        //textVisible = $this.jqmData("textvisible") || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible,
        textVisible = true,
        textonly = !!$this.jqmData("textonly"),
        html = $this.jqmData("html") || "";
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
            text: msgText,
            textVisible: textVisible,
            theme: theme,
            textonly: textonly,
            html: html
    });
}

$(document).on("click", ".show-page-loading-msg", function() { showLoadingPage(); });
```

When I click on a link whose class is `show-page-loading-msg`, it's supposed to trigger `$.mobile.loading`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a small delay to help the loader to display.

```
setTimeout(function() {     
  $.mobile.loading('show');
}, 10);
```

Comment: This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da7y5vcL/2/) works on my iPhone version 9.3.1. Could you check it out?

Comment: Works for me as well. But it doesn't seem to work when the link is pointing to another page. Can't verify this on the fiddle. Try here : http://hortistock.fleurondanjou.fr/testloader.php